# Find sum of indexes in big list, that satisfies some property

Tags: c++, comparative-review, c++17

Task:

> We have this big list of (signed) integers.
>   We are interested in finding every index "idx" (zero-based, of course) in this list, that has the following property: The sum of the integers preceding (but not including) index idx is equal to the sum of the integers followin (again not including) idx. i.e.: (Referring to our list of integers for a moment as "A[]" and the number of integers in the list N), then we want every index
>   idx for which the following is true:
>   A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[idx-1] == A[idx+1] + A[idx+2] ... + A[N-1]
>
> Note that there is likely to be more than one index "idx" in the list that satisfies this property.
>
> Write code that finds every index in our big list that has this property.  Then, sum up every index that you found, and that is the answer to question 1.   For reference, given the array [-7,1,5,2,-4,3,0], the answer we are looking for is 9 because indices 3 and 6 have the property we are looking for  (-7 + 1 + 5 == -4 + 3 + 0  and  -7 + 1 + 5 + 2 + -4 + 3 == 0) and 3 + 6 = 9. satisfies this property.   Write code that finds every index in our big list that has this property.  Then, sum up every index that you found, and that is the answer to question 1.
>
> For reference, given the array [-7,1,5,2,-4,3,0], the answer we are looking for is 9 because indices 3 and 6 have the property we are looking for  (-7 + 1 + 5 == -4 + 3 + 0  and  -7 + 1 + 5 + 2 + -4 + 3 == 0) and 3 + 6 = 9.

I wrote two variants of code:

#### First read the file in `std::string`, and then parse it in `std::list<int>`, and finally, count the answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

uint64_t calc_answer(const std::list<int>& list)
{
    int left_sum = 0;
    int right_sum = std::accumulate(list.begin(), list.end(), 0);

    uint64_t index_sum = 0;
    int curr_index = 0;

    std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), [&] (int val) {
        right_sum -= val;

        if(left_sum == right_sum)
            index_sum += curr_index;

        left_sum += val;

        ++curr_index;
    });

    return index_sum;
}

std::string read_file(const fs::path& file_path)
{
    if(!fs::exists(file_path))
        return "";

    std::ifstream infile{file_path.string()};

    std::string data{""};

    std::string row{""};
    while(std::getline(infile, row))
        data.append(row);

    return data;
}

struct Facet : std::ctype<char>
{
    using ParentT = std::ctype<char>;

    Facet(std::size_t refs = 0) : ParentT(make_table(), false, refs) {}

    static const mask* make_table()
    {
        static mask char_table[table_size];
        static int fake = (std::copy(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size, char_table),
                           (void)fake, 0);

        char_table[','] |= space;

        return char_table;
    }
};

std::list<int> parse_raw_data(const std::string& raw_data)
{
    std::istringstream iss{raw_data};
    iss.imbue(std::locale{iss.getloc(), new Facet{}});

    std::list<int> data{};

    using ISIt = std::istream_iterator<int>;
    std::copy(ISIt{iss}, ISIt{}, std::back_inserter(data));

    return data;
}

int main()
{
    const fs::path DATA_PATH{"data.txt"};

    std::string raw_data = read_file(DATA_PATH);

    if(raw_data.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "File 'data.txt' not found or empty. Terminate..." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::list<int> data = parse_raw_data(raw_data);

    std::cout << "Sum of indexes that satisfies specified propery: " << calc_answer(data) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Read it right away in `std::list<int>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

uint64_t calc_answer(const std::list<int>& list)
{
    int left_sum = 0;
    int right_sum = std::accumulate(list.begin(), list.end(), 0);

    uint64_t index_sum = 0;
    int curr_index = 0;

    std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), [&] (int val) {
        right_sum -= val;

        if(left_sum == right_sum)
            index_sum += curr_index;

        left_sum += val;

        ++curr_index;
    });

    return index_sum;
}

std::list<int> read_file(const fs::path& file_path)
{
    if(!fs::exists(file_path))
        return std::list<int>{};

    std::ifstream infile{file_path.string()};

    std::list<int> data{};

    std::string number{""};
    while(std::getline(infile, number, ','))
        data.push_back(std::stoi(number));

    return data;
}

int main()
{
    const fs::path DATA_PATH{"data.txt"};

    std::list<int> data = read_file(DATA_PATH);

    if(data.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "File 'data.txt' not found or empty. Terminate..." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Sum of indexes that satisfies specified propery: "
              << calc_answer(data) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure which version of solution is more effective

Comment: Most of the time `std::vector` is faster than `std::list`. I don't spot any reason for using `std::list` here, I could be wrong. The function `std::list<int> read_file(const fs::path& file_path)` can be changed to `bool read_file(const fs::path& file_path, std::list<int> &data)` to avoid making a copy.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I'm think than using `std::vector` in this context is incorrect because i have very long sequence and allocation of a solid piece of memory of this size is costly. Moreover, i don't using operations such as `[]` for access to elements of the sequense and I'm use only iterators. Therefore, using `std::vector` loses meaning. Maybe I wrong

Comment: "*allocation of a solid piece of memory of this size is costly*" Not on x64; in any case, if _that's_ your concern then you should be using `std::deque`; `std::list` is almost never the right answer.

Comment: Also consider that `std::list` is going to require 2-3x the memory as `std::vector`, and the allocations are all going to be very small; in addition to the additional memory consumption, this is terrible for memory fragmentation in real scenarios. Again, never `list`. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn what is the advantages of std::list before std::list? It's just an adapter and, according to the logic of the problem, I need to iterate through the container, instead of using the queue.

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg : `deque`, not `queue`. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn, yep, but what's wrong with `std::list`?

Comment: Perhaps [edit] to be a bit more specific on the input format.  From reading the code, it appears that you're expecting comma-separated decimal values, perhaps over several lines, and delimited by end-of-file - is that correct?

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg : It consumes a **lot** of memory since it's node-based; it's slow because it's node-based; and it has exactly zero upsides for this problem. You need a compelling reason _to use_ `list`, not to avoid it – it's good for solving one or two very specific problems, and you don't have those problems here.

Comment: @ildjarn I'm not against 3rd party libraries, but in this task I wanted to practice my knowledge of the stdlib. I would be grateful if you would concentrate on it, but mention alternatives

Comment: Do a web search for this term *"std::vector versus std::list"*. This is a well known issue in C++. The consensus is that `std::vector` is better. People debate whether or not `std::list` is totally useless or is it useful in some special cases, for example in a hypothetical problem where you are doing random insert/delete and nothing else. But you don't have that here.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani : Regarding your first comment, return values don't copy since C++11 (they move or get elided) so that's not relevant for `c++17`. Regarding your last comment, random insert/delete would be terrible for `list`, too, since it doesn't have random-access iterators; it's really only useful if you need its iterator invalidation guarantees. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks, I didn't know that about c++17. Also earlier I said `std::vector` is faster *"most of the time"*, it should really say *"nearly always"*. The asker may wish to run a test between the two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two-pass algorithm looks like a good choice (although it's unclear why you're using `std::list` - change that to `std::vector` or add a comment to justify it).

Some comments:

## Think about the ranges of the integer types

Since you have many `int` inputs, you will likely need something larger to store the accumulated sum:

```
long left_sum = 0;
long right_sum = std::accumulate(list.begin(), list.end(), 0L);
```

## When reading into string, parse each line separately

`std::string read_file()` could produce a very large string.  Instead, we could read a line at a time, and add the elements it contains, much as in the second implementation.

Comment: You are right, the list is not needed. I will take into account your recommendations. Thank you very much!